# Cypress REST calls - how to address field in JSON response body?

Tags: json, rest, cypress, httpresponse

I want to verify the JSON response from REST endpoints, so I cannot use the “should” method because it targets the DOM of a web page (which I don’t have – only REST API available).
My JSON response looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 111,
    "createdAt": "2021-09-14T16:19:29.803",
    "datasetId": "cypress-datasetId2",
  },
  {
    "id": 112,
    "createdAt": "2021-09-14T16:19:29.874",
    "datasetId": "cypress-datasetId",
  },
  {
    "id": 113,
    "createdAt": "2021-09-14T16:30:37.101",
    "datasetId": "cypress-datasetId3",
  },
]
```

I don’t know in advance how many datasets the response will contain. I don’t know the counter of “id” as well. I need to find out if a certain datasetId is contained in the response. I test for:

```
   it('Validate the datasetId of any entry - expect', () => {
       cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8040/data-sets',
       }).then((response) => {
        expect(response.body).to.deep.equal({datasetId: 'cypress-datasetId3'})
       })
   });
```

The AssertionError comes up:

```
expected [ Array(6) ] to deeply equal { datasetId: 'cypress-datasetId3' }
```

at the code position of: ”.equal”.
So it does not tell what the result looks like, only what it expected and that it went wrong.
How can I check for the presence of a certain field in any of the datasets I get as response? Or what allowed me to identify the whole dataset, e.g.

```
  {
    "id": 113,
    "createdAt": "2021-09-14T16:30:37.101",
    "datasetId": "cypress-datasetId3",
  },
```

And return that as a result?

One of the many alternatives that I tried was:

```
   it('Validate the datasetId of any entry - should', () => {
       cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8040/data-sets',
       }).its('body').should('deep.contain', {
           datasetId: 'cypress-datasetId3'
       })
   });
```

Which results in

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected [ Array(6) ] to deep include { datasetId: 'cypress-datasetId3' }
```

The database is empty, so there should be no delay for seeking data sets.

What does work is to address a specific dataset in the array but typically I cannot know this in advance:

```
   it('Validate the datasetId of the first entry - include', () => {
       cy.get('@data-sets')
        .its('body').its('0').its('datasetId').should('include', 'cypress-datasetId');
   });
```

How can I make my approach more generic and independent from the result order?

Comment: Are you trying to validate that your response body contains this `{
    "id": 113,
    "createdAt": "2021-09-14T16:30:37.101",
    "datasetId": "cypress-datasetId3",
  },` ?

Comment: No, I'm not interested in the timestamp for now. I want to check if any of the datasets in the body of the response contains the named attribute and its value.

Answer (score 1):

The response is an array, so you could `.map()` to the `datasetId`

```js
cy.request({
  ...
}).then((response) => {
  const datasetIds = response.body.map(item => item.datasetId)
  expect(datasetIds).to.include('cypress-datasetId3')
})
```

To get that whole object, use `.find()`

```js
cy.request({
  ...
}).then((response) => {
  const found = response.body.find(item => item.datasetId === 'cypress-datasetId3')
  cy.wrap(found).as('dataset)
})

cy.get('@dataset')
  .its('datasetId')
  .should('eq', 'cypress-datasetId3')
```

Comment: Those two did not work for me. I got the error messages "response.map is not a function", "response.find is not a function". Do those commands have prerequisites?

In 2nd example, the second " ' " in the as() function is missing.

Comment: That means the response is not actually what you have shown. I'm guessing you meant the `response.body`  is the array shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert one entire section of the array you have to use `deep.include`. Something like this:

```js
it("Validate the datasetId of any entry - should", () => {
  cy.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8040/data-sets",
  }).then((response) => {
    expect(response.body).to.deep.include({
      id: 113,
      createdAt: "2021-09-14T16:30:37.101",
      datasetId: "cypress-datasetId3",
    })
  })
})
```

Or if you just want to assert that the `datasetId` values. For that first you have to extract the values from the json into an array and then assert it, something like this:

```js
it("Validate the datasetId of any entry - should", () => {
  cy.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8040/data-sets",
  }).then((response) => {
    var datasetIdArray = [] //this will have all the datasetid's
    for (var index in response.body) {
      datasetIdArray.push(response.body[index].datasetId)
    }
    expect(datasetIdArray).to.include("cypress-datasetId")
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, both examples work well for me. The first one only succeeds if all elements are known before which fails for me for "createdAt" because I don't know the creation date in advance. The second one is fitting better. How can I make the second one find a substring in all "datasetId2", "cypress-datasetId3" etc.? How can I change the output from "expected [ Array(50) ] to include cypress-datasetId" to "expected datasetId to include cypress-datasetId"?

Comment: What is the substring that you want to validate ?

Comment: For example "datasetId" to output "cypress-datasetId3", "datasetId4" etc. Can it find all datasets with that substring or will the test be successful when the substring is found for the first time?

Comment: So now your `datasetIdArray` contains the values `[cypress-datasetId, cypress-datasetId2, cypress-datasetId3]`. So now for all these elements you just need to validate the substring `datasetId ` for all the elements.